# Virtual Machine Library not updating

Tags: windows, vmware-fusion, update

I have a problem with my library window.
I use to have a XP VM, which I deleted and now have a Vista VM.
Every time I start Fusion, the XP VM shortcut will still be in the library (File not found), and the Vista VM won't be.
I have tried re-installing Fusion but the same XP shortcut keeps coming up.
Fusion doesn't seem to be updating the list of VM I currently have for some reason.
Any ideas?
Lots of thanks

Jeremy

Comment: Belongs on superuser.com

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to remove them from the list by right clicking them and selecting "Delete" from the context menu.